# java.lang.NullPointerException -using opencv and android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I tried to make [this](http://yus-repo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Android/apps/objtrack/) code work, but I have this error and I don't know how solve it:

> 03-23 21:51:44.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-23 21:51:44.705:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1628): at
>   org.projectproto.objtrack.SampleViewBase.surfaceCreated(SampleViewBase.java:107)

Comment: According to the LogCat, you should start on line 107 in SampleBaseView. A variable on that line is null...  If it is `mCamera` please read about [`open()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29) and how you'll have trouble if you are using an emulator but haven't setup a camera.

Comment: Show us what's in line number 107 in SampleViewBase.java file.

Comment: that what I have in line 107 to 115:

mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                synchronized (SampleViewBase.this) {
                    System.arraycopy(data, 0, mFrame, 0, data.length);
                    SampleViewBase.this.notify(); 
                }
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
            }
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mCamera` seems to be `null` because `Camera.open();` did not return a reference to a camera.

There are different possibilities for that. One might be a missing camera permission in your manifest file. Check it for `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

At my Nexus 7 I experienced a problem with `Camera.open()` as well because for some reason `Camera.open(0)`, which is the same as `Camera.open()` returned null but `Camera.open(1)` returned a `Camera` object of my front camera. May be this is a general issue with devices which only have a frontcamera, but I don't know.

Anyway, this should be the place for you to look at.

[Camera | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29)